# Larger thumbnails in Image Viewer (eog) or gThumb

Tags: dconf, thumbnails, eog, gthumb

I'm looking at images in full-screen mode with the thumbnail strip - both gThumb and eog work well, but the thumbnails are very small. So:

- In eog, I go to [bar menu] > image gallery. The thumbnails seem to be 90px max size. In dconf editor, I found:

  - org.gnome.eog.ui.image-gallery-position - lets me put it on the left;
  - org.gnome.eog.ui image-gallery-resizable - makes it resizeable but a larger size just shows eg 2 columns of small thumbnails
- Meantime in gThumb, when I view an image in full screen, I again get the thumbnail strip - 95px images. In prefs, I can change:

  - General > thumbnails in viewer - bottom or side
  - Browser > thumbnail size - this affects the size of the thumbnails in file browsing mode, not in full-screen viewer mode

I've also tried various other viewers but they don't seem to have a full-screen+thumbnails view. Any idea as to where the setting may be?

Answer (score 3):

**1. gThumb**

Resizing thumbnails in gThumb is only possible in **Browser view**, as you mentioned in your post.

**2. eog**

I didn't found any hidden property to resize the thumbnail size in eog, too.

So I downloaded the **code** (eyes of gnome), and found out how to resize the thumbnails. (*I think in gThumb it will be similar.*)

First you have to download the source code. I suggest to use Ubuntu sources `apt-get source eog`, but of course you are free to use github.
Don't forget to install library dependencies with `apt-get build-dep eog` .

Change into the `./src` directory and open the `eog-list-store.h` file with an editor of your choice. Search for the following line:

```
#define EOG_LIST_STORE_THUMB_SIZE 90
```

The number **90** is the pixle size of the thumbnails. Change the value to the size you need, and configure and build eog. You can test the fresh compiled program with `./build/src/eog`.

A demonstration that it works is shown below; the left one has a thumbnail-width of **50**, while the right one has a width of **150**.

[image]

**eog** is programmed to be a light-weight and fast image viewer. I like the design and simplicity. If you think that resizing of thumbnails should be a feature for all, you are welcome to place your ideas on this [link](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome/PlaceForNewIdeas).

**3. digiKam**

digiKam is a professional photo management with the power of *Open Source*.
It's easy to resize thumbnails and includes a database (sqlight, sql, ...). It is really fantastic! You can order your pictures, search, make tags, ... by ease.
You can install it with

```
sudo apt install digikam*
```

or download the newest **AppImages** on the [digiKam webpage](https://www.digikam.org/). Make it an executable and run it!

[image: digikam screenshot]

**4. xnview**

As an alternative to your problem, I suggest you to use [**xnviewmp**](https://www.xnview.com/en/). You can install it via snap

```
sudo snap install xnviewmp
```

or simply download the app-image at this [download-link](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1170376/startdownload?file_id=1520301485&file_name=XnView_MP-0.89.glibc2.17-x86_64.AppImage&file_type=application/x-executable&file_size=60628304&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdl.opendesktop.org%2Fapi%2Ffiles%2Fdownloadfile%2Fid%2F1520301485%2Fs%2F4a3aa7777faf0dc1a397f4043e388d32%2Ft%2F1531660159%2Fu%2F%2FXnView_MP-0.89.glibc2.17-x86_64.AppImage). Change the permission to executable and run it.

Below are window screenshots of xnviewmp with two different sizes of thumbnails.

[image]

Note: XnView MP is provided as FREEWARE (NO Adware, NO Spyware) for private or educational use (including non-profit organizations).